# Is it allowed to repackage Oracles JDBC driver?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, licensing

I would like to distribute my Java program as a JAR file. My program requires the Oracle JDBC driver, which is also delivered as an JAR file. But the `java -jar` command accepts only one JAR file. Therefore I have to merge the two JAR files. This can be done quite easily but am I allowed to do that? Am I allowed to distribute my program as a JAR file containing the contents of the Oracle JDBC JAR file?

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming one, and so does not belong on SO.

Answer (score 5):

> But the java -jar command accepts only one JAR file.

That's not correct. Your JAR file can contain a Manifest with a Class-Path: entry which can name the Oracle .jar file.

Comment: @ceving Of course it's an answer. The OP just has to name the Oracle JAR file in the manifest. It's a much *better* answer than repackaging, with all the risks that entails.

Comment: ceving IS the OP :) So even though this is a proper answer, OP just doesn't like it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Fancy that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can package Oracle JDBC drivers into your jar file, as long as you are not modifying the jar file or any of the file there in. In some of the libraries it is required to include the license files also as part of your distribution - you need to read the license details of the respective jar files. Generic Oracle distribution license terms can be found here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html

Regarding the `java -jar` part of your question please refer following explanation:

To launch the executable jar file we use the command `java -jar executable.jar`

JVM would look into the manifest of jar file and execute the main method of main class - that you specify in jar file. Any dependency of the application can be satisfied by classpath settings - we dont need to specify all the dependency jar files while launching the application.

There are different ways of classpath settings:

- Set the system classpath (on Windows `set CLASSPATH=app1.jar;app2.jar;driver.jar;` and on Unix/Linux `export CLASSPATH=app1.jar:app2.jar:app3.jar` ). This method is useful when you have control over system variables and it is controlled environment, this method is not preferred for distributing applications to client
- Mention the classpath while launching the application. This can be done by using `-classpath` option of java comman - for example `java -classpath app1.jar;app2.jar;driver.jar -jar executable.jar` this method is useful for quick testing and if the number of jar files to be referred are less
- Specifying the mainfest classpath. This is the best option for packaged application. We can specify the dependencies in the manifest classpath, like this  `Class-Path: app1.jar app2.jar driver.jar`

Note: please use proper delimiters in classpath entries, for example on windows `;` is the delimiter for classpath entry, on unix `:` is the delimiter and in manifest class path you have use space  as delimiter. Also where ever app1.jar/app2.jar/driver.jar is mentioned you have to use absolute or relative path of jar files

Comment: The `-classpath` option is ignored when the `-jar` option is used. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Comment: The license you are referring to allows the redistribution as long as it is necessary for my application. But it does not specify anything about the way how the redistribution is allowed. The question is: is it only allowed to redistribute the original ojdbc6.jar or is it also allowed to redistribute the class files of the ojdbc6.jar file in a new jar file?